# Touchpad for Razer Blade doesn't work for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I have a new Razer Blade 2016 and installed ubuntu 16.04 on it. However, I can't get the touchpad to work, although the buttons do. I have to use an external mouse.

Here's the output from xinput:

```
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Any thoughts?

```
$ uname -a
Linux greenshell 4.7.6-040706-generic #201609300531 SMP Fri Sep 30 09:33:47 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And also

```
$apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:
  Installed: 1.8.2-1ubuntu3
  Candidate: 1.8.2-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 1.8.2-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I have no idea what driver your using.  What;s the output of `synclient -l` ?

Comment: synclient -l
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

Comment: xinput --list-props 15 suggests evdev. I've played around with things and tried libinput, with no luck.

Comment: You m ean 42-synaptics.conf? I tried putting one in there, but xinput --list-props still tells me that it's using evdev, and I can't tell why.

Comment: no, I meant evdev as you said "xinput --list-props 15 suggests evdev"

Comment: Ah I thought you meant to get synclient to work. Either way, I tried evdev with no luck.

Comment: Sorry. You reviewed this: https://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/howto/configure-input.html ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -a`

Comment: Done. I'm also confused why I can't even get synpatics to try to take over, it's always evdev

Comment: also add output of `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Comment: Added that as well.

Comment: Are you using a custom kernel? my 16.04 box with all updates is using  4.4.0-45-generic #66. I don't believe that kernel is currently supported on Ubuntu

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the kernel in use is not currently supported in Ubuntu

Comment: I tried bumping up the kernel at someone else's advice, the touchpad doesn't work in the 4.4 kernel either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poured through dmesg and figured it out. Turns out it was due to having the nolapic flag set in grub. Took it out and touchpad works now.

When booting the laptop, wait for the Grub screen. When 'Ubuntu' is selected, press E to edit the startup options. Make sure that the line that starts with linux does not contain the 'nolapic' flag (this disables APIC, which the touchpad apparently requires). Press F10 to resume booting.

Once Ubuntu loads, the touchpad should work. To make the change permanent edit /etc/default/grub as well (make sure GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT does not contain the 'nolapic' flag).

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted! Do you think you could expand on this a bit so that those who aren't too clear on what grub is and how one changes kernel boot parameters could benefit from your experience? Thank you! Ping me when your finished and I'll upvote it. ';-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't log in here very often. Finally got around to it!